# for loop not working as expected in Batch

Tags: batch-file

Hi i am new to batch scripting. I've been trying to assign output status of my jar file to my **heartBeatTime** variable. The problem is this works in cmd. But when I run as batch it just doesnt work at all. Any clues why?

```
set currTimestamp=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2% %time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%
set appCount=0
set ids=9516
set trialCount=1
set abortCount=1

:checkPublish
for %%f in (10003202 10003207 10003257 10003203 10003232 10003227 10003209 10003213 10003234 10003239 10003240 10003216 10003226 10003238 10003206 10003231 10003252 10003219 10003251) do (
java -jar appPublishCheck.jar %%f >temp
set /p heartBeatTime=<temp
if currTimestamp LEQ heartBeatTime(
set /a appCount=%appCount%+1
)
)
set finalCount=%appCount%
set appCount=0
if %finalCount%==0 goto :wait10
else goto :wait5

:wait10
set /a abortCount=%abortCount%+1
if %abortCount%==25 goto :abort
else(
    ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 600000 >NUL
    goto :checkPublish
)

:wait5
set /a trialCount=%trialCount%+1
if %trialCount%==4 goto :runATF
else(
    ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 300000 >NUL
    goto :checkPublish
)

:abort
exit

:runATF
set /a delay=%delay%*60000
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w %delay% >NUL
cd %IATF_HOME%
set drive=%IATF_HOME:~0,1%
%drive%:
for %%f in (%ids%) do ant runATF -DappID=%%f
```

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with the `status` variable and is asking why your batch file crashes.  You will have to paste the actual code into your original question - maybe you have unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Thanx for the help. Spacing between parentheses was the issue. :)
the jar status is being redirected to temp file now, except for the fact that when I am passing it to `status` variable its not. 
the batch console shows as:
`set /p status= 0<temp` .
On echoing the variable it shows NULL.

Comment: Are you echoing it within the loop?  You know that your variable will be set to the last invocation of the java command line and every preceeding one will be lost - if that is the code you are using.

Comment: yes I am echoing it within loop, and I am incrementing it to another variable that is globally declared. If I have that toal equal to some figure, I know how many apps of mine I have had published. Refer my code edit above.

Comment: You are asking questions about code that you haven't included - there is no echo command there and you just added the `set /a` line.  How can you expect people to help you when you aren't giving an accurate picture?

Comment: I have extended and included the code for you to give you the picture. Like I said, I had problems within **for** block. Now that its entering within for block but temp isnt redirecting to the variable. Note this output:
`set /p status= 0<temp` Sorry for the stupid question, but does **0** signify here anything?

Comment: Most of your problems should go away if you remove the percent signs in the `set /a` commands and also if you change your `if` statements with `else` so that the format is `if blah (this) else (that)` or use multi line format but the `else` is written as `) else (` with appropriate brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the status variable there - but delayed expansion is normally needed to evaluate the variable within a loop.

Then add this in the loop:

```
echo "!status!"
```

Comment: I have added the line `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` in the top. Still to no avail. :(

Comment: I wasnt talking about using `status` variable. I use it in subsequent code. Bottomline is it should have created `temp` file in the first place which it dint. Through cmd it does. :( And something is going awry in this loop only, as my batch goes out when it comes in this loop !

Comment: Remove the `> temp` and put a pause on the next line.  You've left us guessing as to what happens.  Also check that the `do(` is really typed as `do (` with the space.

Comment: I just did that. Surprisingly, batch still goes out. One thing I am able to figure out is the fact that if I dont use braces in for loop and just put the execution part of jar file after `do` it works. But as soon as I include the jar file execution within braces, batch goes out? Weird..